# Remainder of division of two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The remainder of the division of $x^3$ by $x^2-x+1$.

I tried doing the traditional simplifying put the answer cannot be a number. The result expected is -1 but I can't seem to reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv x\!-\!1}\,\Rightarrow\, x(\color{#c00}{x^2})\,\equiv\, x(\color{#c00}{x\!-\!1})\,\equiv\, \color{#c0d}{x^2}\!-x\,\equiv\, (\color{#c0d}{x\!-\!1})-x\,\equiv\, -1$

**Remark** $\ $ Essentially we rearranged the polynomial to obtain a rewrite rule $\, x^2 \mapsto x\!-\!1,\ $ which, applied iteratively to any polynomial $\,f(x),\,$ allows us to eliminate all powers of $\,x\,$ greater than $1$, resulting in a polynomial $\bar f(x)$ of degree $\,\le 1\,$ such that $\,\bar f (x) \equiv f(x)\pmod{x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1}.\,$ Therefore $\,\bar f(x)\,$  is the sought remainder (by the *uniqueness* of the remainder in the Division Algorithm).

This method of *modular arithhmetical* computation of remainders works very generally, and it is often more convenient than rote applicaton of the polynomial Division Algorithm. Further, it generalizes to multivariate polynomials - see the Grobner basis algorithm and related methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.

Alternately and somewhat more painfully, we could use polynomial division.